# Can unbuffered channel be used to receive signal?

Tags: go, goroutine

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)

    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        sig := <-sigs
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println(sig)
        done <- true
    }()

    fmt.Println("awaiting signal")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}
```

---

Size one buffered channel is used for receiving signal.

Unbuffered channels provide guarantee of delivery.

Size one buffered channel provides delayed guarantee

---

Can we use unbuffered channel in this scenario? `sigs := make(chan os.Signal)`

Comment: Is this blog post the source of your claims about channels? https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/10/the-behavior-of-channels.html

Comment: @jub0bs yes you are right and this can be tested through code as well

Comment: I disagree with those claims. Whether delivery happens depends on the logic on the consumer side as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [signal.Notify documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#Notify)

> Package signal will not block sending to c: the caller must ensure that c has sufficient buffer space to keep up with the expected signal rate. For a channel used for notification of just one signal value, a buffer of size 1 is sufficient.

So, to answer your question:

> Unbuffered channels provide guarantee of delivery.

This is incorrect. Delivery can only be guaranteed if you know both the behavior of the sender and receiver.

In this case, the sender is non-blocking. So if the receiver is not waiting for a signal, the message will be **discarded.**

> Size one buffered channel provides delayed guarantee

There is no “delay” in a channel. The buffer is just how many items can be stored in the channel.

> Can we use unbuffered channel in this scenario?

The code will *probably* work, but it is not guaranteed to work. The problem is that you don’t know when this line will get executed:

```
sig := <-sigs
```

Any signal which arrives after `signal.Notify` but before `<-sigs` will get discarded (if the channel is unbuffered). Remember that `signal.Notify` is non-blocking—this just means that it will give up instead of wait.

If you don’t want signals to get discarded, use a buffered channel.

This scenario is unlikely, sure. But it is technically possible.

Comment: For your point...."Any signal which arrives after `signal.Notify` but before `<-sigs` will get discarded (if the channel is unbuffered)." Is this correct? Because signal will not get discarded but sender will be blocked on unbuffered channel

Comment: `Unbuffered channels provide guarantee of delivery.` mean sender gets blocked until receiver receives the data. This guarantees the delivery. Data will never get discarded until we exit the program.

Comment: @overexchange https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/os/signal/signal.go;l=232

Comment: @overexchange: According to the documentation, the signal handler **does not block.** Since it does not block, it can do something else if the receiver is not ready. In this case, the signal is discarded. If you want to guarantee delivery, you must use a buffered channel.